# Renault Clio "Check ESP" issue

Tags: engine, renault, clio, traction-control

Since Yesterday I'm getting a warning message "Check ESP" and the engine warning light flashing also please refer to the video which has the similar warnings:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=q4DNiQudjjE

- The acceleration response is really slow when acceleration from a stop.
- Steering wheel is vibrating (Maybe the whole car is vibrating)
- Engine more noisy

What can be the causes of the issues ? and how much will it cost ?

Thank you

Comment: likely an ignition coil problem, pretty simple test really, check out this video https://youtu.be/ftc9MNPblik

Comment: @hellomoto that's correct it's the Ignition coil and spark plug and needs to be changed

Answer (score 1):

After reading the error by the computer it indicates that the Ignition coil and spark plug need to be changed